# Wordpress header and footer plugin bug

Tags: wordpress, plugins, header, footer

I am building a wordpress.org website locally using the kadence template and am using the header and footer builder plugin.

Am following the following tutorial to the letter: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQCWCEEYqm4
However, on mobile and table the dropdown menu does not span full width of the page like in the video. My table and mobile dropdown only takes up a very small width (see screen clip attached).
[image]

I have tried adjusting the content width in page layout but that did not help. I even tried starting with blank pages in case the default page was messing up the layout.
Any help or tips would great.
Many thanks

Comment: please add an example of reproducible code to allow clearer understanding and resolution of the problem